# Flutter center an Icon inside an ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter, dart

**ANSWER:** Adding `padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.zero),` to the `ButtonStyle` did the trick

So, the icons inside an ElevatedButton tend to move righter, but I need it dead centered.

Code for the button:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 5),
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: pressHandler,
    child: icon,
    style: ButtonStyle(
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(color),
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
        RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Which results in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YyCs.jpg

Button needs to be a rounded rectangle, so a lot of solutions do not work.

I've tried IconButton, which requires text and I do not need it.
Using Stack to put the icon with GestureDetector on top of button doesn't really work either, because it looses the CLICK of a button.

And so I'm wondering if there is a proper way to do it?

P.S. Stack approach (closest to visual as it needs to be)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 5),
  child: Stack(children: [
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: pressHandler,
      child: Container(),
      style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(color),
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
            RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
            ),
          )),
    ),
    GestureDetector(child: Center(child: icon), onTap: pressHandler)
  ]),
);
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting a different width and height in sizedbox.

Also, if your'e using a column with **crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch**, all the child widgets will take the screen width.

```
         SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.zero),
                backgroundColor:
                    MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green),
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

If your'e using a custom icon, make sure it has no padding, otherwise will affect the UI.

[image]

Comment: Somehow I forgot about trying to use SizedBox... It did the trick, thanks a lot.

Comment: Always prefeer using SizedBox, it improves the app performance avoiding boilerplate background code with unnecesary attributes. In fact, is recommended by Google and any linter.

Answer (score 0):

You can set min size to your elevated button then remove container.  It works.
You can check dartpad link.
[dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1)

```
  ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: (){},
        child: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
        style: ButtonStyle(
          minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all<Size>(Size(50,50)), //////// HERE
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red),
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
            RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: It sure works, but not in the way I need:
Button become non-square (as they need to be) [Expample](https://imgur.com/a/e0P4zv0) (sizes'r 30|20|10). The closes to the visual I got was with the Stack approach [Example](https://imgur.com/a/TNt1P4q) 
Added it to the question